# I want to make my submit button an href image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a huge issue trying to figure out how to make this agreement form work.
It's designed so people have to accept the terms and conditions to submit it, if they don't check the box then the submit button becomes gray and unavailable. It works perfectly the way it is but now I want to substitute that submit button with this image

it's like an order image that redirects you to the checkout page. I've done a lot of research but I don't seem to be getting the answers I'm looking for. I've tried styling it and everything but nothing works.

I'd really appreciate your help,
Thank you very much!!

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
      }

  }
</script>
</head>
<h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a>
<br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="image" src="image.jpg" alt="Submit">`

Comment: Your html dont have a form element so what is the functionality of Submit button? You can accomplish your requirement with a piece of Javascript code.

Comment: @Punit Sachan I just want to put an image instead of a submit button but give it the function of blocking users to go through if the don't agree with the terms

Comment: @Katina I have posted a solution using href tag and javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the code snippet below, basically it is adding an image inside of the button.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("submit1").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("submit2").disabled = true;
 }

  function activateButton(element) {

      if(element.checked) {
        document.getElementById(element.getAttribute("data-id")).disabled = false;
       }
       else  {
        document.getElementById(element.getAttribute("data-id")).disabled = true;
      }

  }
</script>
</head>
<h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)" data-id="submit1"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a>
<br/><br/>
  <button type="submit" id="submit1" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/570‌​51/250513/13';"><img src="https://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250513/13" alt="Submit"></button>
      <br/><br/>
       <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)" data-id="submit2"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a>
<br/><br/>
  <button type="submit" id="submit2" onclick="document.location.href='https://www.jvzoo.com/b/570‌​51/250513/13';"><img src="https://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250467/13" alt="Submit"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134899/discussion-on-answer-by-noah-i-want-to-make-my-submit-button-an-href-image).

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the submit button is a bad idea, it can give issues for other areas such as accessibility.

What you want is to have form validation and depending on your solution a required attribute.

Check out the following example which is doing what you are trying to achieve.

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-checkbox-required/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript, just HMTL5 and CSS

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">    
    form:valid input[type="submit"]{
        background: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6>
<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="alert('ok');">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" required />  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @romuleald thank you very much for your answer! 
Now, I want to replace that submit button with this <a href="https://www.jvzoo.com/b/57051/250513/13"><img src="http://i.jvzoo.com/57051/250513/13" alt="Tube Cash Blueprint (2M)" border="0"/></a>

It's an image they'll click on and take them to the checkout page. How can I do that? Please

Thank you again!

Comment: @Katina Use a display: none; on the input and a display:block; on tha <a> element

Comment: You are a gem @romuleald. This is how my code looks like with your corrections https://www.screencast.com/t/rCQsaFvt9u and this is how the site is looking https://www.screencast.com/t/rCQsaFvt9u 
It looks perfect but the clients can still go through without checking the box, I want this image to have the same function as the submit button. If they don't check the box the image becomes unavailable. Please help me, you've been very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function disableSubmit() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
    activateButton(checkbox);
 }

function activateButton(element) {
 if(element.checked) {
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").onclick  = function() { submitForm(); };
 }
 else  {
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").onclick  = function() { return false; };
 }
}

function submitForm(element){   
  document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
}

</script>
</head>
<h6> Tube Cash Blueprint Agreement</h6>
<body onload="disableSubmit()">


<form id="testForm">
 <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" onchange="activateButton(this)"/>  Check here to indicate that you have read and agreed to the terms of the <a target="_blank" href="https://johnmichaelmarketing.com/tbc-agreement/">Tube Cash Blueprint Costumer Agreement</a>
    <br/><br/> 
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submitBtn" ><img src="submit_button.gif" height="60px"></img></a>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use two different images, one for enable and another for disable and replace then dynamically using javascript.